# Fedora boots to blank screen and never shows login or other text

Tags: fedora, boot, initramfs

I tried part of [this tutorial](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/#before-installation) and firmly broke my Fedora bootup.

Usually when I boot up, the first thing that happens is I get a screen with my available kernels, I select one, and then it goes to a LUKS password prompt. Then after that it goes blank and then shows the KDE loading icon.

Now I get the GRUB bootloader with all my various kernels from the past and the current one (That stage looks normal). I tried a few of those but in the end, after successful LUKS decrypt prompt, it goes to a blank screen on bootup and that's it. I know the volume is fine since I successfully, decrypted, mounted and copied from the file systems thru live boot.

Here are the changes I made that may have caused this failure:

1. echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
2. Appended ‘rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau’ to end of ‘GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”…”‘. in /etc/sysconfig/grub
3. grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg (I assumed I was using EFI because I believe that was how I installed it)
4. dracut /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
5. systemctl set-default multi-user.target

I did make a backup of the initramfs image so I will bootup on my backup USB system and move the original back into place and also remove the steps 1 and 2 from above that I appended.

However I am very concerned about having messed with grub and initramfs. The boot process can definitely be fixed, I would say since decrypt goes fine.

Any ideas to try first off?